# Rendering Obj Groups in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, vbo

I am new to OpenGL ES, and I'm writing an iPad app that requires me to load a Wavefront Obj file, draw them in OpenGL.  My question is about the most efficient way to render the Obj file groups.

A little background on what I have.  All the parsing/loading of the Obj model is working (I used GLM to load the file), so the tedious stuff is out of the way.  For the base project, I've expanded off the OpenGL ES game template in XCode, and removed all the calls into the shaders.  I'm using GLKit's BaseEffect for my shaders, and loading all my vertex data using VAO and VBO.  For a model with say 16 groups, at init time I'm separating each group into a VAO, with each VAO having a VBO for vertex data and normals (interleaved), and a second VBO for Texture coordinates.  Each group has a material (and sometimes a texture, but for the sake of the question assume only materials).

In my rendering routine (pseudo code below), I am looping through all the VAO's I created for each group, applying the material for the group to the BaseEffect, and then drawing it using DrawArrays (not using DrawElements because I've set the VBO's up so the data is already in indexed order, although it's probably not as efficient as it could be on graphics memory).  This works, and I'm able to draw each model with different materials, but as the group count goes up, my framerate goes down, as I have to spend more time looping through each group in my render function.  For a low model count this is fine, but as I'm adding more models to the app, the frame rate gets well below 30fps, which is my baseline.

```
for (groups in model)
{
    Bind VAO for this group

    Apply Material or Texture (if one exists) for this group using GLKBaseEffect

    Call PrepareToDraw for GLKBaseEffect

    DrawArrays passing it the vertex count for this group

    glBindVertexArray(0)   
}
```

The obvious answer is to simplify the model so that there are less groups, but I am curious if there are any improvements to the rendering routine that could allow me to do the same thing but less Draw calls.  I'd like to still have a detailed obj file, but also have the most efficient rendering I can.

Is this the best method for drawing an obj file where I have to use multiple materials/textures for each group in the file, or is there a way this can be done without looping through each group and drawing them individually?  I'd love to be able to have each obj model have only 1 call into DrawArrays/DrawElements, but I don't see how this can be done and still apply multiple materials/textures to the object.  I keep looking at this code and thinking "there has to be a better way", however I'm not sure what that is.  If I'm missing a blatantly obvious piece of the puzzle, or if you have any suggestions you can provide to optimize this I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've pretty much got the right idea. You can only really have one set of textures, or one shader active at a time, so you have to draw the part of the model that uses that state, switch the state, and draw the next group.

If your performance is degrading as you add more models, you could try to sort your groups such that you draw all the groups with the same state in a row without switching.

So if you're drawing 100 copies of Model, and model has three groups A, B, and C: then instead of doing this:

```
foreach(model)
   set state A;
   glDrawArrays(A);
   set state B;
   glDrawArrays(B);
   set state C;
   glDrawArrays(C);
```

You should do something like this:

```
sort models into groups;
foreach(group)
    set state
    foreach(instance of group)
         glDrawArrays
```

This saves you about 99% of your state transitions (shader switching, texture binding, etc). That will be a big perf improvement.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I'll give this a look and see if this will work.

Comment: This works, except in my solution rather than breaking all my separate objects into similar groups, I created my VAO's in such a way that for a single object, all groups with the same texture/material were combined into a single buffer.  This way a large object with 10 groups that use a common texture would be drawn in 1 pass.  To put it another way, instead of building my VAO based on the object groups defined in the obj, I built it based on the material it uses.  Not quite as efficient as what Tim described, but similar and will work for now.